# Eclipse, Java, Junit4, I want to blackbox test a jar file. Need a little help in setting up

Tags: java, jar, junit4, black-box-testing

We were given a jar file to do blackbox testing on the methods. I know one test is supposed to give us a runtime exception but I'm getting a null pointer exception. My question is do I have this setup correctly and do you guys know where I'm going wrong?

[Package explorer is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgvez.png)

[Single test case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AG6Jr.png)

[Imported JAR file into build path correctly?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Anwof.png)

[Test case that is giving the wrong error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Immmu.png)

[UML Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NP6x8.png)

Comment: Links in the question do not help much(at least unless the actual question is clear otherwise). Please edit the question to include the information.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Eclipse, but from your output it looks like everything is setup fine.

I'm not surprised by the `NullPointerException` either; you called `addCourse()` and passed `null` instead of a `Course`.

This is clearly homework. I don't know what your directions are, but if you don't expect that method to throw NPE, you probably shouldn't be putting nulls in there.

Since the exception you're looking for is `CourseOverlapException`, you probably ought to try adding two `SingleLectureCourse`s that have overlapping time ranges.

Comment: It is homework I just wanted to see why the freebie that he threw us wasn't working the way it should have, he basically said "Null values result in an uncaught runtime exception". I was also figuring out if I had everything setup properly because we didn't really learn how to use jars for blackbox testing so I sort of winged it and I guess I got it to be the way it should.

Comment: A NPE is a kind of runtime exception. Your test should show that you expect it will be thrown, either by adding it to the `@Test` annotation or by catching it in the test and asserting about it.